# Try/Catch - Is it possible to get all of the data generated before exception occured?

Tags: python

This is rather question than serious problem. I have a try/catch part in my code. This part contains the loop which adds new strings to the array. Let's say there are 10 iterations supposed to run. After 8th iteration program raises the exception so the catch is being triggered. Is it possible to get somehow the data (8 strings) from before the catch has been triggered ? 
@edit test code: Can't execute second for loop

```
tabelka = ["1","2","3","4"]
tabelka2 = []
try:
    for x in tabelka:
        if not "4":
            tabelka2.append(x)
        else:
            raise ValueError
except ValueError:
    print("exception occured")

for y in tabelka2:
        print(y)
```

Comment: Any variables you set before the exception occurs stay set, assuming the exception is not allowed to propagate out of the local scope.

Comment: @kaya3 added some code

Comment: `if not "4"` will **always** evaluate to `if False`. `bool("4")` is `True`, and `not True` is `False`. Do you mean `if x != "4"`? Your current code will immediately jump into the else-statement and print the exception. Since nothing was added to `tableka2`, the contents of your 2nd for loop will never be run.

Comment: This code *does* keep the results so far in `tabelka2`; the problem is there are no results so far, because it fails on the first iteration. If it fails on a later iteration then the previous results will still be in the list after the `except` block. So it seems to me that the code in your question already behaves how you want, except for a trivial mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `try` block inside of the `for` block. 
It would be something like this:

```python
tabelka = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
tabelka2 = []
for x in tabelka:
    try:
        if not "4":
            tabelka2.append(x)
        else:
            raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        print("exception occured")

for y in tabelka2:
    print(y)
```

It's not related to your question, but this expression `if not "4"` will always be False, I think it should be `if x != "4":` instead. But I'm not sure of what this code should do, it's just a heads up.

Comment: This solution has the added benefit of trying to process *everything* in `tableka` instead of everything until a "fail" happens.

Comment: That isn't necessarily a benefit; it may be a downside, depending on the context. It's also not the behaviour the question asked for, which was getting just the first 8 strings if it failed after the 8th iteration; not the first 8 and also the 10th.

Comment: Yes @kaya3, indeed. I didn't took it as a downside, but I agree with you, it may not be the expected result.